# How to launch a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a class that extends the broadcast receiver. My question is how will I go about calling on this activity in another class... I tried to create a intent for it but I kept getting a syntax error. Is it another way to start the broadcast receiver?

Comment: Could you provide what syntax error you're getting?

Comment: When talking about an error it is always a good idea to post the exact error description and the code.

Comment: Please post your manifest file and the Intent code you invoke.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent( "mypackage.myaction" );
 activity.sendBroadCast( intent );
```

Where activity is the one that launches your BroadcastReceiver and Intent, an intent that matches the filter of your BroadcastReceiver in your manifest file.

You will do something that looks like :

```
<receiver android:name="your broadcast receiver class" android:label="a name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mypackage.myaction" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Regards,
   Stéphane

Comment: How would my intent filter look in the manifest? for a broadcast reciever?

Answer (score 2):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.mydefinepackage.myactivity");
this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
```

Declare this private class and use above code within myactivity Activity.

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        myOwnMethod();
    }
}
```

Execute this code from any other activity. myOwnMethod will be called then.

```
Intent i =new Intent("com.mydefinepackage.myactivity");
sendBroadcast(i);
```